# Adding a Android Library from a project into the workspace generate a Android Dependencies.Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

When I select the properties to my project then go to Android and add a new Library, the eclipse automatically create a Android Depencies that contains all my .jars.

It does not add the new project to the list of referenced packages. When I try to Run the application I got the error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1. When i realize I have the .jars that i added both in the Android Dependencies and my /gen.

When I delete de Android Depencies I got error in my classes, saying that i´m not referencing the specifics .jar... But I have them in my /gen past.

Any Ideia how to make the eclipse refer to just one .jar?

Answer (score 0):

Library is a special android feature that allows you to use an apk or another android project where you would for example share some code. It's detailed here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

I think that what you want to achieve is just adding a jar as a dependency which can be done with Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries Tabs > Add Jars / Add External Jars.

tl;dr :

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries != Project > Properties > Android > Library

Comment: No I want to add a Android Project that I have in my workspace, the project is marked as : IsLibrary. 

But everytime I try to add the project as Library in :Project > Properties > Android > Library, the eclipse adds the .jar of the project in the AndroidDependencies and also in my /gen folder adds the package with the R.java class of the project.

Comment: And also the eclipse doesn´t add the projectname_src in my main project.

Answer (score 0):

I did these steps to make my app work with the lib-sources using adt 17

- add "lib-sources-project" to workspace

  - import/general/existingProjectsIntoWorkspace
- mark this "lib-sources-project" as android library

  - lib/Properties/Android/IsLibrary must be checked
- Add lib to main app

  - app/buildpath/ConfigureBuildPath/Projects Add "lib-sources-project"
  - app/buildpath/ConfigureBuildPath/OrderAndExport set check for "lib-sources-project" so your lib will be included into the buildresult
  - app/Properties/Android/Library Add "lib-sources-project" to the list.

Note since adt 17 you can have resources in your "lib-sources-project". Android Lint will tell you what you have to change to make it work.

Hoever i haven't succeeded yet to include a jar with resources without adding "lib-sources-project" as described above.

Maybe somebode knows how to do this.